# Downgrading Aperture 3.4.3 library to 3.0

Tags: aperture

Is there a way to open an Aperture 3.4.3 library in Aperture 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attempting to open the library repair tools** by holding down ⌘⌥ while opening that library **and then clicking Cancel** results in Aperture correctly opening it and adjusting the version number in the library file so that it can be normally opened on future attempts.

**Adjustments**, including the updated Highlights & Shadows, **seem to properly downgrade**.

Video available at http://youtu.be/JYKSSJ4CQrQ